# the function of wrapping a widget in another widget has disappeared

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

on a light bulb, the ability to wrap a widget in another, for example, a Container or a column, has disappeared. Maybe this happened after the AS update? If it is possible to return this function, please tell me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a keyboard shortcut. Place the cursor to the widget and press:

For Mac - `Option + Return`

For Windows/Linux - `Alt + Enter`